# Identifying nouns in an array of string

Tags: javascript

I need to find a way to identify if an item in an array is a noun. I really can't think of any way to do this.

The first thing I did was ignore all words with "ly" in the end. But we know many words that aren't nouns doesn't have to have "ly" in the end. Is their a better way to do this? Is their a javascript library that can do this?

Comment: might be you can connect one of these APIs 
http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#web

Comment: Do you want *all* nouns? Or just proper nouns? If you want only proper nouns, [checking if the word starts with a capital](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770028/how-to-find-proper-nouns-in-string) may be a not fully perfect but fairly okay solution ...

Comment: This is not simple at all. Please read [How can I extract words from a sentence and determine what part of speech each is?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/133778/how-can-i-extract-words-from-a-sentence-and-determine-what-part-of-speech-each-i).

Comment: There are absolutely no rules in English that link spelling patterns to parts of speech. There are words that are both nouns and verbs ("fly").

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I need all nouns.

Comment: are you sure you want stick only with javascript. If you can use java, i can suggest you openNLP

Comment: @practice2perfect I've searched about that and I really want to use it. Unfortunately in my web design subject I'm only allowed to use javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use this

http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/wngloss.7WN.html

it has endpoints for JSON and XML (you can make a simple GET request for each word and get the type of the word from the responded json e.g.

http://chriscargile.com/dictionary/json/cow

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is called a pos tagger. The [pos](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pos) `node.js` module does exactly that.

The natural nodejs module also comes with a wordnet interface, which you can use.